# Migration issue Manifest-2 to Manifest-3 ( service worker inactive )

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am migrating my chrome extension from manifest version 2 to 3.
There is a problem in injecting the file with the click of the extension icon.

```
Manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,    
    "name": "Name of Extension",
    "description": "description",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting"
    ]
}
```

Background.js - Manifest version 3 ( This code is not working )

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      files: ['"function.js"']
    });
});
```

background.js - Manifest version 2

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "function.js"});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `tab` parameter as described in the documentation for [onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#event-onClicked)
2. Specify tab's id as described in the documentation for [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript)
3. Remove the nested quotes in the file name

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    files: ['function.js'],
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it's working!